# sum of amount earned medals for 1-day, 2-day and 3-day based on daily cohort users

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need some help with cohort analys.

I have:

1. users

   ```
          user_id   installed_at
          111       01.03.2020
          112       01.03.2020
          119       02.03.2020
          120       02.03.2020
   ```
2. table of earned medals

   ```
          user_id   created_at  earned_medals
              111   01.03.2020  1
              112   01.03.2020  1
              111   02.03.2020  2
              112   02.03.2020  2
              119   02.03.2020  1
              120   02.03.2020  1
              111   03.03.2020  3
              112   03.03.2020  3
              119   03.03.2020  2
              120   03.03.2020  2
   ```

I need acumulated earned medals

```
       Daily_cohort-user       1-day    2-day   3-day
       01.03.2020                 2       6      12
       02.03.2020                 2       6     null
```

Comment: Add sample data and expected result please

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Those queries are product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh PostgreSQL

Comment: @Jens I updated question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
with cte as (
select
t2.installed_at, t1.user_id,created_at,
sum(t1.earned_medals) over (partition by t1.user_id order by t1.user_id,created_at)  as "sum_"

from earned_medals t1 inner join users t2 on t1.user_id=t2.user_id
)

select 
installed_at,
sum(sum_) filter (where created_at-installed_at =0 )   as "Day1",
sum(sum_) filter (where created_at-installed_at =1 )   as "Day2",
sum(sum_) filter (where created_at-installed_at =2 )   as "Day3"
from cte
group by 1
order by 1
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2b950e63f36b93bc6bd7319a72725c6a)

you can add more days as required in your query like below

```
sum(sum_) filter (where created_at-installed_at =3 )   as "Day4",
sum(sum_) filter (where created_at-installed_at =4 )   as "Day5",

...
...
...
```

Comment: thank you so much! It's works fine for me! @Akhilesh Mishra